# cannot find module 'meteor'

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, mocha.js

I want to test a meteor app with mocha framework from the command line:

> mocha **/*/*spec.js --compilers js:babel-core/register

all tests works fine but when tests file begin with :

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Factory } from 'meteor/dburles:factory';
```

import meteor etc .. I receive error :

> Error: Cannot find module 'meteor/meteor'

so my questions are :

1. How can i test a meteor app without the command "meteor test" ?
2. How i must bootstrap mocha to run meteor tests ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed meteor to the local NPM modules directory (`npm install`)? Also you may need to run the tests using `meteor` CLI. See [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/testing).

Comment: yes tried npm install and meteor npm install, and i need to run tests without the meteor cli.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use practicalmeteor:mocha. So I have scripts in my package.json like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "meteor --settings settings-development.json",
    "test": "meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha --port 5000 --settings settings-development.json",
    "chimp-watch": "chimp --ddp=http://localhost:3000 --watch --mocha --path=tests",
    "chimp-test": "chimp --ddp=http://localhost:3000 --mocha --path=tests"
  },
```

And these are some simple tests:

```
    /* eslint-env mocha */
    /* eslint-disable func-names, prefer-arrow-callback */
    /* eslint no-console: ["error", { allow: ["log", "warn", "error"] }] */

    import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
    import { assert } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
    import { resetDatabase } from 'meteor/xolvio:cleaner';

    import { checkLog } from '../apiHelpers.js';

    import { insertLog } from './methods.js';
    import { addLog, addLogPromise } from './insertHelpers.js';
    import { getLGSitemId, getLGSitemType, getLGScreateDate } from './generalHelpers.js';
    import { getLDSevents, getLDSevent, addEvent } from './dataHelpers.js';

    describe('Log Tests', function() {
      beforeEach(function () {
        if (Meteor.isServer) {
          resetDatabase();
        }
      });

      if (Meteor.isServer) {

        it('insertHelpers: addLog', function () {
          let testLogId = '';

          try {
            testLogId = insertLog.call(addLog('someDodgyId', 'doc'));
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }

          assert.typeOf(testLogId, 'string');
          assert.typeOf(checkLog(testLogId), 'undefined'); // if it runs correctly, undefined
        });

        it('insertHelpers: addLogPromise', function () {
          addLogPromise('someDodgyId', 'doc')
            .then((result) => {
              assert.typeOf(result, 'string');
              assert.typeOf(checkLog(result), 'undefined');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              throw new Meteor.Error(err);
            });
        });

        it('generalHelpers', function() {
          const testLogId = insertLog.call(addLog('someDodgyId', 'doc'));
          assert.typeOf(testLogId, 'string');

          // Tests
          assert.equal(getLGSitemId(testLogId), 'someDodgyId');
          assert.equal(getLGSitemType(testLogId), 'doc');
          assert.typeOf(getLGScreateDate(testLogId), 'date');
        });

      }
    });
```